# Data processing with Dimple.js

Tags: date, d3.js, type-conversion, dimple.js, stacked-area-chart

I'm novice in D3.js. I'm trying to build area chart within dimple.js lib, here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<div id="chartContainer">
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.0.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time.v2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
    d3.csv("Video_Game_Sales.csv", function (data) {
      data = dimple.filterData(data, "Company", ["Microsoft", "Nintendo", "Sony"])
      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
      myChart.setBounds(70, 30, 340, 330);
      var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["Company","Year"]);
      myChart.addPctAxis("y", "Global Sales");
      var s = myChart.addSeries("Genre", dimple.plot.area);
      s.lineWeight = 1;
      s.barGap = 0.05;
      myChart.addLegend(430, 20, 100, 300, "left");
      myChart.draw();
    });
  </script>
</div>
</html>
```

In consle output was: `Error: <text> attribute x: Expected length, "Infinity".`

So I mentioned that data in Year column looked like that: 1,996, 1,997... 2,016 etc. So I decided to convert into data format with this line of code:
`x.dateParseFormat="%Y";`

But I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 problems, not in code but in csv-file itself:

1. in csv delimeter: it was
2. in separator in data values itself - there was `,` and I changed it to `.`, so it worked!!! :)

PS I didn't change anything with Years field data type.